# Does getSize() in Android include the height of the status bar?

Tags: android, height, pixel, android-statusbar

Is there a way to tell if `getSize()` includes the height of the status bar?  From testing on a few different phones it seems it does on some but not on others and it is frustrating when trying to make everything in the layout line up properly.

After spending a week on this problem and checked Google's documentation & many other posts here on Stackoverflow (about getting the screen size in pixels via `getSize()`, `getRealSize()`, `getMetrics(DisplayMetrics metrics)`, `getRealMetrics(DisplayMetrics metrics)`, etc ... I still have no clue about it.

[This picture is giving a better picture of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouPIi.jpg)

On some phones and according to the above picture, the line 'Y/2' should be exactly at `size.y / 2` (exact half of the screen between the navigation & the status bars), but is actually **not** in the middle : The 'Not X' distance on my picture is therefore equal to 'X - getStatusBarSize()'.

I have to add that i am using a ring object with an innerRadiusRatio 2.1 in XML. 
But i don't think it's the reason because once i am using the code below, it works on phones where getSize() seems to include the height of the status bar :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Screen dimensions
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

       //Get the screen dimensions
       maxWidth = size.x 
       maxHeight = size.y - getStatusBarSize();
   }

private int getStatusBarSize() {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

While it works simply with `maxheight = size.y` on others phones (where it does not include the status bar height).

Thanks in advance guys for any help !

Comment: May I know what are you trying to achieve? maybe there is an alternative way to do it more efficiency

Comment: What i want to achieve is cutting the screen's height in half with maths (dynamically) and on some phones i get the half of the screen + `statusBarHeight`. 
I can notice this because there is a fixed symetry in my main layout, in any other cases i think i would not notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing to the same issue more or less and this could be helpful :

```
// Get the size between the status & the navigation bars
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

// Real size of the screen (full screen)
Point realSize = new Point();
Display realDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
realDisplay.getRealSize(realSize);

//Get the screen dimensions
maxWidth = size.x;
maxHeight = size.y;

if (realSize.y - getNavBarSize() == size.y || realSize.y == size.y) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: getSize() includes the status bar size");
    maxHeight = size.y - getStatusBarSize();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you.
So the answer is yes, sometimes the `getSize()` method indeed includes the status bar height...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question and this is how I solved it.

- Display.getSize() only sometimes includes the status bar height.
- For the solution with .getRealSize() you also need the navigation bar height.

With the following solution you don't need the navigation bar height:

```
View contentView = requireActivity().getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT);
int height = contentView.getHeight() - statusBarHeight - actionBarHeight;
```

(You might have to get the height in contentView.post() if it returns 0.)